# Printing element of an array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have an array of strings

```
char *arrayOfStrings[];
```

and I would like to print the second string in this array.

```
printf(" Second string is %s." , arrayOfStrings + 1);
```

What's the correct code?
The error is : format specifies type 'char * ' but the argument has type 'char ** '

Comment: It gives an error : format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **'

Comment: Hmm, sorry, my bad. What works is `*(arrayOfStrings + 1)`

Answer (score 4):

You access an array like this: `arrayOfStrings[1]`. Don't pay attention to any advice to use pointer arithmetic (that's when you write crazy unreadable stuff like `*(arrayOfStrings+1)`).

Answer (score 1):

you should try below code

```
printf("Second String is %s", *(arrayofStrings + 1));
```

Explanation:
arrayofStrings is having base address of array. And you need to have the value stored in second location of array as that is having address of string.